# Diagonal Arrows in a Table/Array Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrays

I'm trying to replicate the following diagram.

[image]

My first thought was to use `tikzcd` and draw arrows between the empty nodes, but that wasnt resulting in the same appearance. Any guidance is appreciated, and there's certainly no need for anyone to fully TeX this diagram out! Just a simple example of the same style would be more than helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is one approach to creating this diagram.

Instead of a matrix (like with TikZ-CD) or an `array` environment we create this *field*  of numbers by specifying the number of occurences in each row and placing those at full integers of the *xyz* coordinate system (unless in odd rows where we shift everything about 0.5 to the right).

For the right spacing, we can adjust the `x` and the `y` key.

This way, every place in this matrix has a coordinate where *−y* stands for the row (starting with 0) and *x* stands for the column (starting with 0), although for the columns we're counting them in steps of 0.5.

The special second row (or −1st to be precise) gets an extra loop while everything else gets placed in the main loops where

```
{5/0, 4/1, 7/0, 1/-1}
```

means that five 0s, four 1s, seven 0s and one −1 get placed.

The `n = …` keys may help to **n**udge start or end points of the line in certain direction, away from the center of the position in the matrix. Of course, you can just input directly the resulting coordinate but it might help to think of positions in the matrix to find the correct points.

---

With the default font size and the wide minus sign it makes it hard to draw the lines between the numbers without them intersecting the text while having a reasonable width for the whole diagram.

You will have this problem with every approach, though.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  y=6mm, x=12mm,
  /pgf/foreach/occ list/.style={
    remember=\nextOCC as \prevOCC (initially 0),
    evaluate=\OCC as \lastOCC using int(\prevOCC+\OCC-1),
    evaluate=\lastOcc as \nextOCC using int(\lastOCC+1),
    var=\OCC, var=\NUM},
  n/.is choice, n/.cd,
  u/.style={shift=(up:.5)},      d/.style={shift=(down:.5)},
  l/.style={shift=(left:.25)},   r/.style={shift=(right:.25)},
  ul/.style={shift={(-.25,.5)}}, dl/.style={shift={(-.25,-.5)}},
  dr/.style={shift={(.25,-.5)}}, ur/.style={shift={(.25,.5)}},
]
\foreach[
  count=\rowY from 0,
  evaluate=\rowY as \offset using int(isodd(\rowY))
] \ROW in {
  {5/ 0, 4/1, 7/0, 1/-1},
  {4/ 0, 1/1, 3/2, 1/ 1, 6/ 0, 1/-1, 1/-2},
  {4/ 0, 2/1, 2/2, 2/ 1, 5/ 0, 2/-1},
  {3/ 0, 3/1, 1/2, 3/ 1, 4/ 0, 3/-1},
  {3/ 0, 8/1, 3/0, 3/-1},
  {2/ 0, 4/1, 1/0, 4/ 1, 2/ 0, 4/-1},
  {1/-1, 1/0, 4/1, 2/ 0, 4/ 1, 1/ 0, 4/-1},
  {1/-1, 4/1, 3/0, 4/ 1, 4/-1, 1/ 0},
  {1/-1, 1/0, 3/1, 4/ 0, 3/ 1, 1/ 0, 3/-1, 1/0},
  {2/ 0, 2/1, 5/0, 2/ 1, 2/ 0, 2/-1, 2/ 0},
  {3/ 0, 1/1, 6/0, 1/ 1, 3/ 0, 1/-1, 2/ 0}%
}
  \foreach[occ list] in \ROW
    \foreach \X in {\prevOCC, ..., \lastOCC}
      \node at (\X+.5*\offset, -\rowY) {$\NUM$};

\foreach[occ list] in {5/0, 4/1, 6/0, 1/-1}
  \foreach \X in {\prevOCC, ..., \lastOCC}
    \node at (\X, -1) {$\NUM$};

\draw ([n=l]   0,   -10) -- ([n=u]  5,   -0)
      ([n=ul]  0,   - 5) -- ([n=dr] 2.5, -10)
      ([n=l]   2,   - 6) -- +(down:2.5)
      ([n=l]  11.5, - 6) -- +(down:3)
      ([n=dl]  3.5, -10) --  (6.5,  -4) -- ([n=dr] 9.5, -10)
      ([n=d]  10.5, -10) -- +(5.5,  11)
      ([n=dl] 14.5, -10) -- +(2.5,   5)
      ([n=d]  13.5, -10) -- +(-5.5, 11)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]